# Use a loops values outside of the loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'd like to use the values of this loop outside of the loop.

```
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'numberposts' => null,
            );

            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    $image_id = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
                    echo ',';
                }
            }
```

As it loops through it spits out a range of image ID's separated by a comma.

```
 1, 2, 3, 4
```

After it has finished looping I'd like to use that sequence as it is spit out above in the function below.

```
get_jig(array('ids' => $image_id));
```

Currently when I use the loop variable for the `$image_id` It just gives the last ID, when I need all of them. Apologies for the noobness. I understand it's probably very easy for some of you, I'm still getting my head around PHP.

Comment: Is that all the code you have or is there more to it ?

Comment: What is the function get_jig() doing?

Comment: Use a second `foreach` loop over `$attachments`?

Comment: How would I go about that @MarkBaker?

Comment: `foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    $image_id = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
                    echo ',';
                } foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    get_jig(array('ids' => $attachment->ID));
                }

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to create an array before the loop and insert the IDs into it as you go.

```
$ids = array(); // Create an empty array here
if ($attachments) {    
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $image_id = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
        echo ',';
        $ids[] = $image_id; // Insert the ID into the array
    }
}
```

Then you could use it in this function that looks like it needs to take an array

```
get_jig(array('ids' => $ids));
```

If get_jig doesn't take an array, but needs a comma-separated string, you can use implode() to create the string from the array:

```
get_jig(array('ids' => implode(',',$ids)));
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, just need the empty array though. You know how I might output it as values rather than this `Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => 17 [2] => 16 )`

Comment: @MikeJackson I edited the answer to address this, if I understand what you're asking properly.

Comment: Yus! That's it. I knew implode would probably have to be in somewhere, though just didn't know the syntax. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a string like "1, 2, 3, 4". But you are creating a file with a string like "1" then you overwrite that files with "2" and so on.

You want to replace

```
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $image_id = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
        echo ',';
    }
}
```

with

```
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         $image_id .= (isset($image_id) ? ", " : $image_id = "") . get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
    }
}
```

This paste shows this all working.. http://viper-7.com/qZt7It